# Looping collection.fetch in backbone.js a certain number of times

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to fetch a collection `x` times, incrementing a counter each time. The issue I am having is that since I need to render a view in the callback, and since `.fetch()` is asynchronous, I cannot simply perform a javascript loop. I would like to somehow tell it in the `success` callback to call itself again, without getting into an infinite loop.

Here's what I have:

```
@collection.fetch
      data: {q: letters, i: i}
      success:
        @renderList()
```

How can I make this run `x` times, incrementing `i` each time, while waiting until `@renderList` is complete before running it again?

**UPDATE**

So, I'm making progress - this seems to be working, but it looks terrible:

```
@collection.fetch
      data: {q: letters, i: 1}
      success:
        @collection.fetch
          data: {q:letters, i:2}
          success:
            @collection.fetch
              data: {q:letters, i:3}
```

Also, the success callback is giving me this warning in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Advice?

Comment: How could it *ever* have worked? You've forgot the `->` or `=>` character after each `success:` part. [This is your current output](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%40collection.fetch%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7Bq%3A%20letters%2C%20i%3A%201%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20success%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40collection.fetch%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7Bq%3Aletters%2C%20i%3A2%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20success%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40collection.fetch%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7Bq%3Aletters%2C%20i%3A3%7D%0A).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try recursive function like this (it's only example):

```
recursiveFetch = (collection, successCallback, counter, data) ->
    if counter == 0
        successCallback()
        return
    data.i = counter
    collection.fetch
        data: data
        success: -> recursiveFetch(collection, successCallback, counter-1, data)
```

and call it like this:

```
recursiveFetch(@collection, => @renderList(), i, {q:letters})
```